# How does one provide an unmarshaller for a Scala trait in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I am using **Akka HTTP** and **spray-json**.

I have the following model hierarchy defined:

```
trait Animal {
  def weight: Int
  def name: String
}

case class Dog(
  weight: Int,
  name: String
  //other specific attributes
) extends Animal

case class Cat(
  weight: Int,
  name: String
  //other specific attributes
) extends Animal
```

I also have defined a correct custom `JsonFormat` for trait `Animal` as:

```
implicit val AnimalFormat = new JsonFormat[Animal] {
  // custom read method
  // custom write method
}
```

Now I want to have a generic POST method to create `Animal` instances:

```
post {
  entity(as[Animal]) { animal =>
    complete {
      //save Animal          
    }
  }
}
```

I want this POST method to accept JSON of both type `Dog` and `Cat`. The JSON formatter is also in scope. But I am getting the following compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[models.Animal]
```

I don't understand why the implicit formatter is not being detected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got around the problem. All I had to do was use `RootJsonFormat` instead of `JsonFormat`. So, the formatter looks like this now:

```
implicit val AnimalFormat = new RootJsonFormat[Animal] {
  // custom read method
  // custom write method
}
```